# Where is the crash-free sessions metric in firebase?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

Since Fabric will be deprecated soon, I've migrated my project from Fabric to Firebase. In Fabric, Crashlytics reported crash-free users and sessions metrics, but in firebase I can only see the crash-free users metric. 
Where can I see the crash-free sessions?

[image: crash-free users]

Comment: Nice stats ;) how big is your user base?

Comment: Were you able to find where it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crashlytics announced on it's Twitter account that it'll be available slightly after Fabric shuts down. You can see it here : https://twitter.com/crashlytics/status/1222959191121432577?s=21

Comment: Well, Fabric is dead, but still no Crash-free sessions on Firebase :/

Comment: @Sébastien It's currently "In Progress", according to https://get.fabric.io/

Comment: Sep 22 2020 and still no crash free sessions metric. Also the get.fabric.io site has not been updated since May 2020